# Status of Move-VM

Tags: developer

Is the Move-VM project still alive? If so, where can I follow the status? I was told there is a #move-vm channel in the Solana Tech Discord, but there isn't. The Solana docs say the Move VM approach is outdated... Any replacement efforts going on?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's still active. The channel is in the Solana Tech Discord but under the name `#proj-move`, which is probably why you might have missed it. The last update there was yesterday.

There's also an active [repo](https://github.com/solana-labs/move) for it.